# Как ловить ошибку в таком примере Rx2

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть такой код

```
return Observable.just(new Date())//
                     .map(//
                             iEndDate ->
                             {
                                 Date latestDate = (Date) mEmployeeCallsByDate.keySet().toArray()[mEmployeeCallsByDate.size() - 1];

                                 if (latestDate.after(iEndDate))
                                 {
                                     return latestDate;
                                 }

                                 return iEndDate;
                             }//
                     )//
                     .blockingFirst();
```

Как как тут ловить ошибку? Допустим налпоинтер

Если использовать `subscribe()` вместо `blockingFirst` то там можно на эррор подписаться, а тут как?

Comment: в чем смысл данного кода?

Comment: @SviatVolkov Просто проверка,  нужно вернуть либо `latestDate` либо `endDate` , согласно условию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, примерно так.

```
        Observable.just("")
            .map {
                //тут просто произошло что-то плохое
                throw RuntimeException()
                return@map ""
            }
            .onErrorReturn {
                //пишем в лог и подсовываем что захотим
                Timber.e(it)
                return@onErrorReturn ""
            }
            .blockingFirst()
```

Comment: Вопрос не по теме, а как проверить `instanse of` ? Просто `cast` и если не сработало то ловить ошибку? Но ведь бывает когда есть несколько проверок когда один раз проверяем если это инстанс если нет то проверяем если это инстанс другой, как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Так же как и с обычными исключениями, в onErrorReturn приходит Throwable, можно проверять через instance of, а потом уже работать как с конкретным исключением.